# c# Search Result From Contains String Class Contains List For Find String

Tags: c#

```
    public class WorkingList
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool Working { get; set; }
    }
```

Class WorkingList is Contains String

i want use like

```
       public List<WorkingList> Work = new List<WorkingList>(); 
       bool ContainsCheck=false;
       foreach(WorkingList list in Work)
       {
          if(list.Name.Equals("FindName")) { ContainsCheck = true; break }
       }
```

I Want Know Easy get List contains String Method!

using linq ? or anymethod / and

```
          public class TopClass
          {
             public List<WorkingList> Work = new List<WorkingList>(); 
             public string TopName { get; set; }
          }
```

i want know easy way Topclass.Work.Name contains string result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool ContainsCheck = Work.Any(list => list.Name.Equals("FindName"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
  ContainsCheck =work.any(i=>i.Name=="FindName");
```

Comment: To up the educational value of your answer, perhaps provide some minimal description on what the code does or why it is a solution. Not everyone might be experienced enough to understand.